# Angular Integration Test - Testing APi

Tags: angular, unit-testing, integration-testing

I am currently learning about Integration Tests in Angular.

As I understand it, with these tests you can test the result of a call to an API and verify that the result obtained is what is truly needed. But the doubt is that many tutorials teach but using a so-called Fake or a Json that is in the same Angular app (it is burned in the APP), which is not obtained by calling an API, but contains the same value or result of the API and I don't see the point in this, because for me the idea is to test what the API returns and not have to test a Fake burned in the app, since at some point the API can change the returned structure and Because of the test at the time it would not throw the error.

Am I right?

Any suggestions or opinions, please.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have understood, what you want is end-to-end testing : testing that your application works, from client to server.

In angular, integration testing is more about testing if your component is integrating well with other components : this is different from unit testing, where you isolate your component and mock all of its dependencies.

Again, this is my understanding, so I might be wrong here !